# detect when a hyperlink is clicked anywhere

Tags: c#, winforms, hyperlink

Is there a way to do the fallowing:
I want to create an piece of software (with C#) which will always be executed, when a hyperlink will be clicked anywhere in windows. Or this application is executed and get a message, when a hyperlink is clicked. In this application I should get the clicked hyperlink and cancel calling the browser when it will be a specific link so I can do my own logic.
Concret: I have a CRM-Application. Now it should be possible to enter a link in word, excel, etc. which should not be executed in the browser instead it should calling something in my CRM-Application.
I hope, someone could help me, how I can do this.

Comment: no, it is a real requirement!

Comment: You should resolve this by using protocol-prefixes instead of catching hyperlinks which would be insanely complex and over-engineered. Look into registering your own prefix (perhaps... crm://mylink)

Comment: @davee You should make that an answer, and elaborate a little. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could resolve this by registering a protocol-prefix for your application rather than trying to catch hyperlinks which would be insanely complex and over-engineered.

Look into registering your own prefix. One example is the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431449/detect-when-a-hyperlink-is-clicked-anywhere#comment15080622_11431449) davee made.

From http://kb.mozillazine.org/Register_protocol:

> Once registered, the protocol can then be handled by the program you specify, such as your browser or a third party viewer. This means that a hyperlink ( e.g. foo://fred) can use the handler for protocol foo to open the file named fred.

Microsoft has an article with a reasonably thorough C# example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx